# Can you use Michaelis–Menten kinetics to model the ATP production rate for glycolysis and OXPHOS with glucose as a substrate?

Tags: kinetics, biochemistry, enzyme-kinetics

I am an applied mathematician researching cell metabolism, but I have little  experience in biochemistry. Currently, my PI and I are considering using [Michaelis–Menten kinetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics) to study how varying glucose availability can impact a cell's rate of ATP production. As such we are considering or substrate to be glucose and our product to be our product:

\begin{align}
    v(\mathrm{gly})&=\frac{V_\max(\mathrm{gly})\cdot [\text{glucose}]}{K_\mathrm{M}(\mathrm{gly})+[\text{glucose}]}; \tag{1}\\
    v(\mathrm{ox})&=\frac{V_\max(\mathrm{ox})\cdot [\text{glucose}]}{K_\mathrm{M}(\mathrm{ox})+[\text{glucose}]}, \tag{2}
\end{align}

where $\mathrm{gly}$ and $\mathrm{ox}$ represent [glycolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycolysis) and [oxidative phosphorylation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxidative_phosphorylation) (OXPHOS), respectively. I have my doubts about using Michaelis–Menten kinetics given that OXPHOS and glycolysis use more then one step and more then one enzyme.

However, I was wondering if there is a method for averaging the $K_\mathrm{M}$'s for each step for an overall estimate for $K_\mathrm{M}$ for each metabolic pathway? I appreciate any advice you can offer and other possible modeling suggestions.

Comment: Course-grained metabolic model, e. g.  http://complex.upf.es/~andreea/2006/Bib/Browning.DevelopmentMinimalCell.p.pdf

Comment: Your Km should probably not be taken literally but rather serve as a saturation parameter. I'm not sure the the rate of glycolysis depends primarily on the amount of glucose present. For example, the blood sugar levels are high after a meal, but glycolysis is not necessarily at maximum capacity. Here is some further reading for mathematicians or physicists: https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/103/32/11868.full.pdf

Comment: ATP production from glucose can generally be modeled pretty well by saturation kinetics, but the Ox-phos part is trickier. Can you share what organism you are working with?

Comment: Thank you these are excellent reads. We are working with humans cancer cells.